# Can I use source test1.sh with gnome-terminal -x?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am executing 2 shell scripts from the main using source.

```
main.sh
#/bin/sh

a=1
b=2
c=3

gnome-terminal -x sh -c ". ./test1.sh|less" (note the source ".")

gnome-terminal -x sh -c ". ./test2.sh|less"
...
...

test1.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "a="$a #doesn't print anything
```

I was able to do following 2 separately but when I combine, I am not able to access variables of main into other files
1. gnome-terminal -x sh -c "test1.sh|less" #able to execute in separate terminal
2. . ./test1.sh #able to access variables from main.sh in test1.sh

Comment: If you are only piping the output of the test scripts to `less`, it's not clear that there is any difference between sourcing the script and executing it. There are no other commands running that could make use of any modifications to the environment made by the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, the first is that you do not export the variables.

In this case, you must do an:

```
export a b c
```

after setting the variables.

The second problem is that the terminal windows will be launched reusing a pre-existing gnome-terminal session if one exists. This pre-existing session will have no idea of these environment variables. As a result you need to pass the option `--disable-factory` to the gnome-terminal command e.g.

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x sh -c ". ./test1.sh|less"
```

and then you will see the proper value in the window.

Comment: One question: in this case will I be able to modify the exported variable in test1.sh and use it back in my main shell script?

Comment: Environment variables can only go down the chain from parent to child, modifications made in the child will not affect the parent. In this case, the gnome-terminal is a child, so it's changes would not be reflected in the parent. If you want to communicate changed values back to the parent, you will need to use some other mechanism such as a pipe or file.

Comment: Yes, and not only is the direction of this relationship top-bottom, but it gets broken at 'birth' time - the child gets a copy of its parent's environment, and any change in the parent does not affect the child.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables have to be exported for them to be accessible to child processes:

```
export a=1
```

etc.

Comment: This also assumes that gnome-terminal doesn't hand-off the opening of a new terminal window to the already launched gnome-terminal instance, and thus never sees the environment variable

Comment: Yep, totally forgot about that